# Fallback condition in a mysql select statement

Tags: mysql

I want to put a condition into MySql statement. If that is even possible?

This is my current mysql select statement

```
SELECT *
      FROM `validproduct`
      WHERE `visible` = 1
      AND `typeid` = 2
      AND `sizeid` = 3
      GROUP BY `productid`
```

So at the moment, I am selecting products with sizeid = 3. What I want to do is to select products with size = 1, and if that doesn't exist, then select sizeid = 3.

My validproducts table contains a list of products with up to 6 different sizes associated with it (which in turn have different pricing). I want to return all of my products, with the lowest sizeid (which will also have the lowest price available for that product). Not all products have a sizeid 1.

So my return data will be something like product A (sizeid 1, $x); product B (sizeid 3, $y) etc

Comment: You want to select `sizeid = 3` if _no rows_ exist with `sizeid = 1`?

Comment: As per your question, it seems that you want to use a if condition in an sql query, which is not possible...

Comment: @AswinMurugesh It is possible, just not via `IF/ELSE` logic...

Comment: From deleted answer: _Hmmm. My validproduct table has many products, each productid has more than 1 size with it. So I want to return all the products, but each product have the lowest sizeid availble from it. So some products will have sizeid 1, and others will have 3. Will this return my full product list, with each line producing its lowest sizeid?_    That's a totally different query. You had better clarify it in the question above and I'll delete this. If I have time, I'll attempt to redo it. What I have above will return all of either size 1 or size 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
SELECT 
  vp1.* 
FROM 
  validproduct vp1 
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      productid, MIN(sizeid) as minsize 
    FROM 
      validproduct 
    WHERE 
      visible = TRUE AND
      typeid = 2
    GROUP BY
    productid
  ) AS vp2
ON 
  vp1.productid = vp2.productid AND 
  vp1.sizeid = vp2.minsize AND 
  vp1.visible = TRUE AND
  vp1.typeid = 2
GROUP BY 
  vp1.productid;
```

**Explanation:**

The outer query is actually what you already have. The inner sub-query finds the minimum sizeid for every product. By joining the two you get what you want.

[PLZ SEE THE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1891/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird, but OK I guess...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT COALESCE(i2.i,i1.i)m FROM ints i1 LEFT JOIN ints i2 ON i2.i = 3 WHERE i1.i = 1;
+------+
| m    |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+

SELECT COALESCE(i2.i,i1.i)m FROM ints i1 LEFT JOIN ints i2 ON i2.i = 11 WHERE i1.i = 1;
+------+
| m    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

or maybe...

```
SELECT i FROM ints ORDER BY FIELD(i,1,3) DESC LIMIT 1;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
```